# How to use Background Worker component to update UI

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, arabic

Actually I am trying to read arabic localized pdf files, because every file takes almost 5 or more seconds to get it processed so I thought to use background worker component in winforms to have the progress updates as well.
I need to process at any 1 time near to 200 files as of now.

This is my code which is time consuming and was running on the main UI thread and causing the UI to freeze.

```
  private void ButtonLoadBills_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      foreach (var file in _filesWithPath)
                {
                    _pdfProcessor = new PdfProcessor();
                    var res = _pdfProcessor.ProcessPdf(file); // Time consuming work is being done here

                    if ((res) && (_pdfProcessor.ProcessedDocument != null))
                    {
                        PdfDocuments.Add(_pdfProcessor.ProcessedDocument);
                    }
                }
}
```

When I put this code under Background Worker

```
  private void ButtonLoadBills_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          BwProcessPdf.RunWorkerAsync();
        }          
 private void BwProcessPdf_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var pdfDocuments = new BindingList<PdfDocumentModel>();
        foreach (var file in _filesWithPath)
        {
            _pdfProcessor = new PdfProcessor();
            var res = _pdfProcessor.ProcessPdf(file); // Time consuming work is being done here
            if ((res) && (_pdfProcessor.ProcessedDocument != null))
            {
                pdfDocuments.Add(_pdfProcessor.ProcessedDocument);
            }
            BwProcessPdf.ReportProgress(1,file);
        }
    }



private void BwProcessPdf_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            labelControl1.Text = string.Format("{0}: {1}", PDF_PROCESSING, e.UserState);
        }

        private void BwProcessPdf_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {}
```

Questions:

1. Is this the right way I should do it.
2. Using background worker thread, how can I update my label control(see attached pic) to tell user that xyz.pdf has started processing, because as far as I know I cannot update UI from DOWork event.

[image: Form for reading Arabic pdf file]

Thanks

Comment: write the code in `ButtonLoadBills_Click` that file **has started processing** and then write `BwProcessPdf.RunWorkerAsync();`

Comment: You can update the UI via ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events. Also you can setup your own custom event handlers to update the ui.